# argument of type 'ModelFormMetaclass' is not iterable

Tags: python, django

please I'm a beginner in django. when i connect my class in the veiws.py i get and error which i don't really understand but when i dont connect it, it works with the class

this is my views.py

```
class AudioCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'main:login'
    model = Audio
    fields = AudioForm
    # fields = ['title','audio','author', 'categories']
    template_name = 'main/events/create_audio.html'
```

this is my forms.py

```
class AudioForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Audio
        fields = ['id','title','audio','author', 'categories']
        # widgets = {
        #     'audio': forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'application/pdf'}))
        #
```

please and this is the  error i get when i try to use it

```
File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\MYDJAN~1\PRIEST~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 551, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\MYDJAN~1\PRIEST~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 256, in __new__
    apply_limit_choices_to=False,
File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\MYDJAN~1\PRIEST~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 152, in fields_for_model
    if fields is not None and f.name not in fields:
TypeError: argument of type 'ModelFormMetaclass' is not iterable
```

Can anyone help me i dont understand why im getting this error

Comment: You can't say `fields = AudioForm`, you have to specify the fields

Comment: please how do i specify the fields

Comment: Just like in the line you have commented out

Comment: then please i want to add more features to the form. so then how will i be able to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your issue. But in your `CreateView`, you need to specify the fields as follows:

```
fields = ['id','title','audio','author', 'categories']
```

And also in your widget line, you seem to be missing a closing }, i.e. it should be:

```
 widgets = {
        'audio': forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'application/pdf'}))
           }
```

I don't know if this was your issue, or if that was just a copy & paste error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is what you pass in `fields` in the `CreateView`.
Because you want to use a `Modelform`, you can specify the form using the `form_class` attribute.

```
class AudioCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'main:login'
    model = Audio
    #Specify you form there, the actual AudioForm define the fields to use
    form_class = AudioForm 
    template_name = 'main/events/create_audio.html'
```